# A question about two rules in isomorphism and cardinality

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

In class I have encountered the next two rules:

- the next models - $\langle \mathcal{P}(A),\subseteq \rangle$ and $\langle \mathcal{P}(B),\subseteq \rangle$ are isomorphic, if $A$ and $B$, have the same cardinality.

I had a chance to use this rule in a certain question, but I wondered to find out that I was wrong. Now, I am not sure when I can apply this rule. The question was finding isomorphism between $\langle \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})\cup\{\mathbb{Z}\},\subseteq \rangle$ and $\langle \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\subseteq \rangle$, which are not isomorphic. But on the next question, I have found that: $\langle \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}\cup\{\mathbb{Z}\}
),\subseteq \rangle$ and $\langle \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}),\subseteq \rangle$ are indeed isomorphic, and I cannot see the differences at all, because in both scenarios we have the same cardinalities of the models. Therefore, I need an extended explanation of when I can apply this rule, etc.

- if $B=\{X\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z}):x\ is\ finite\}$ then $\left|B\right|=\left|\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{Z})\right|=\left|\mathbb{R}\right|$.

Can you give me an explanation for why is true?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you translating from another language? In places where you write "the next things" and then specify the things, it is better English to write "the following things" (e.g. "the next two rules" should be "the following two rules", and "the next models" should be "the following models")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\mathcal P(\Bbb N)\cup\{\Bbb Z\}$ is not of the form $\mathcal P(\text{something})$, and therefore the rule that is only about posets ofa that form cannot be applied.

We can see that $\langle \mathcal P(\Bbb N)\cup\{\Bbb Z\},\subseteq \rangle$ and $\langle \mathcal P(\Bbb N),\subseteq \rangle$ are not isomorphic because only the first has a unique second-largest element, i.e.,
$$ \exists a\,\exists b\,\forall c\colon (c=a\lor c\subseteq b)\land a\ne b$$
holds in only one of the two posets.

---

Moreover, in your second question, the set $B$ of *finite* subsets of $\Bbb Z$ is only countably infinite (do you see how you can write it as countable union of countable sets?), hence strictly smaller than $\Bbb R$ in cardinality.

Comment: So the first rule only works when the models' world is in the form of $\mathcal{P}(something)$?
Btw, what about the second rule?

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @user12121 Yes, the first rule is only applicable to show isomorphisms between some $\langle \mathcal P(A),\subseteq \rangle$ and $\langle \mathcal P(B),\subseteq \rangle$. If you want to investigate isomorphism between models not of this form, it cannot be applied. Because the only statement it makes *is* about models of this from.